# R maps - Filter coordinates out when plotting points in map

Tags: r, maps, coordinates

I have a large data frame of events locations (longitude, latitude). See a sample below:

```
events <- structure(list(lat = c(45.464944, 40.559207, 45.956775, 44.782831, 45.810287, 35.913357, 43.423855, 45.2359, 45.526025, 41.91371, 46.340833, 40.696482, 42.367164, 41.913701, 41.89167, 46.046206, 41.108316, 45.514132, 45.688118, 37.090387, 43.446555, 41.913712, 46.614833, 45.368825, 41.892168), lon = c(9.163453, 8.321587, 12.983347, 10.886471, 9.077844, 10.560439, 6.768272, 9.23176, 9.375761, 12.466994, 6.889444, 17.316925, 13.352248, 12.466992, 12.516713, 14.497758, 16.871019, 12.056176, 9.176543, 15.293506, 6.77119, 12.466993, 15.194904, 11.110711, 12.516085)), .Names = c("lat", "lon"), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I would like to plot only the events that happened in a given country (for instance, Italy).

The following plots all events:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(maps)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(getMap(resolution="low"), xlim = c(14,14), ylim = c(36.8,47))
points(x=events$lon, y=events$lat, pch = 19, col ='red' , cex = 0.6)
```

How can I filter out the events that fall outside the boundaries of the country ? Thank you in advance for help and support.

Comment: take a look at `sp::over`. you can use that to filter out only the points that are in a particular polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign polygon map to an object:

```
m = getMap(resolution="low")
```

convert events into an `sp` object -- first longitude, then latitude:

```
pts = SpatialPoints(events[c(2,1)])
```

assign CRS:

```
proj4string(pts) = proj4string(m)
```

plot points inside any of the polygons:

```
points(pts[m,], pch = 3)
```

select points inside Italy:

```
it = m[m$ISO_A2 == "IT",]
points(pts[it,], col = 'blue')
```

(this uses `sp::over`, but behind the scenes)

Comment: thank you. I spent the whole afternoon trying with `sp::over` but always missed relevant params here and there and I ended up going nowhere. This step-by-step solution is easy and efficient. Great !

Comment: `over` has a vignette on the CRAN page of `sp`, to complement its documentation which is somewhat terse. The dominant use cases are spatial selection (see above) and aggretation, both reuse `over` under the hood.

Comment: Just wanted to say +1 to @EdzerPebesma...it took a lot of Googling this week to finally stumble upon this concise answer, which made sense even to a R newbie like me.